# Systemd: How to make two services mutually exclusive but run both?

Tags: services, systemd

I've got two systemd timers and their associated services:

- `a.timer` triggering `a.service`
- `b.timer` triggering `b.service`

Both services perform housekeeping tasks using the system package manager so they **must not be run in parallel** (in fact, either service fails if it is started while the other is running, as both try to create a lock file).

My aim is to ensure that both services do get run so `b.service` shall be delayed if `a.service` is running and vice versa.

If I understand [systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) correctly I cannot use `Conflicts=` as this would actively stop one service when the other one is being started. I cannot use `After=` or `Before=` either (with `Type=simple`) as this would delay the second service only until the first one is *initialized* (i.e. still running).

One solution, to my understanding, would be the combination of `Type=oneshot` and `After=` as oneshot makes systemd consider the unit *active* (and immediately *dead*) after the main process has terminated. On the other hand, using `Type=oneshot` is explicitly discouraged for possibly long-running tasks.

One could also put both tasks in one `.service` unit using

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c 'first-command; second-command'
```

but I'd consider this very ugly as it would bind the execution interval of both services together.

So what is the most systemd'ish way of having multiple services that depend on the same exclusive resource?

Comment: There's a [relevant thread on the mailing list](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2019-October/043586.html), started on the same day as this post. For the benefit of others - the suggestions were to handle the blocking lock externally to systemd, using `flock` or a blocking lock in the target application itself.